# Ruby One-liner Regular Expression to replace each character \d with "*"?

Tags: ruby, regex

How do you replace each character up to a certain point with another character as long as a condition is met?

```
string = "401200******7777"

string.gsub!(/^\d+/) { |m| "*" * m.length }

puts string
# ************7777
```

Is there an easier/better way to do this?

Comment: What don't you like about your solution?

Comment: @marzagao, I suppose he wants universal solution for any kind of `gsub` and any condition of stop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't try it right now, but this should do the trick:

```
string.gsub!(/(\d)(?=.*\*)/, '*')
```

Comment: I just want to let you know that I'm going to ++ you to hell and back for that link.

Comment: What if the input was `111***222***333`? Of course, it probably isn't an issue. You could solve in with a lookbehind, but not in Ruby.

Comment: @Zabba - no look-behing, as far as I remember.

Comment: @Kobi, that was in old 1.8.x before Oniguruma regex engine, as far as I know.

Comment: @Nakilon - Excellent news! I see it is working on [ideone](http://ideone.com/IUGpM), but not on [rubular](http://rubular.com/r/PgDKDPvnIz). Hmm. I see it happened almost 2 years ago. Oh well. Thanks!

Comment: @Kobi, now we know, that Rubular is outdated )

Comment: `string.gsub!(/(?<!\*)^(\d+)(?=.*\*)/){ |i| '*' * i.length }` should work for Nakilon's second test, as well as Kobi's comment, I'd think. You could replace the ^ for a \s or sosuch if the string actually happened in the middle of a line, but you'll have to figure that one out yourself : )

Comment: OMG )))) But it became the same, that viatropos has posted, only regex *upgraded*...

Comment: Should be something like `/(?<=^\d*)\d(?=\d*\\*)/`

Comment: Actually, you can drop the look ahread, and make it work on Nakilon's third example: `/(?<=^\d*)\d/`

Comment: @Nakilon - Does ruby support variant length lookbehind? ideone cries: http://ideone.com/JSVEv

Comment: @Kobi, maybe no. Sorry, I don't know *look-behind* and other advanced regex magick )

Comment: @Kobi: Other than sorta-emulating it with Perl's \K switch (which works wonders for positive look-behinds, but makes me want to eat my own face with negatives), is there any language that supports those? (in Perl you could just use (*COMMIT) in an if-else pattern and be done with it /endfanboy)

Comment: @Hugmeir - As far as I know Perl does support it, so does PHP, .Net, and Python - I'd say most major flavors support look-behind in any length. Java is missing from this list, and JavaScript is where I miss it the most.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm... the only way I invented now is using **flag variable + two regexes**:

```
string = "401200******7777"
flag = true
string.gsub!(/./) { |i| (flag &&= i[/\d/]) ? "*" : i}
```

But it's not *oneliner*...